# How to determine the smallest value of three integers in MIPS without using loops

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I was able to get the user input as shown in my code but I'm desperately incapable to get the smallest number.
Thanks a lot...

Here are the instructions for this.

"Write an assembly program to read three 32-bit signed integers from the user. Determine the smallest of these three numbers and display this result. Don’t use loops. Prompt the user for each entered integer."

```
.data
Msg1: .asciiz "Enter the first integer: "
Msg2: .asciiz "Enter the second integer: "
Msg3: .asciiz "Enter the third integer: "
Msg4: .asciiz "the the smallest numberis: "

.text
     # Print the first message
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, Msg1
 syscall

 # Prompt the user to enter the first integer
 li $v0, 5
 syscall

 # Store the first integer in $t0
 move $t0, $v0

 # Print the second message
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, Msg2
 syscall

 # Prompt the user to enter the second integer
 li $v0, 5
 syscall

 # Store the first integer in $t1
 move $t1, $v0

 # Print the third message
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, Msg3
 syscall

 # Prompt the user to enter the third interger
 li $v0, 5
 syscall

 # Store the first integer in $t0
 move $t2, $v0

 # Determine the smallest Number
 slt $s0, $t1, $t0
 beq $s0, $zero, L1
```

Comment: Are you still allowed to branch?  If so, it's pretty straightforward to conditionally jump over a move instruction to get max of the first two, then do it again.  Otherwise look for branchless min / max sequences.  (IDK if MIPS has a `cmov`, or if you have to build it out of SUB / SRA / AND).

Comment: can you do it for two numbers? Then after you have smallest from two, instead of printing result just do smallest from two again (the smallest from previous result vs third value), and you have smallest from three. It's just few more lines of code.

Comment: min(a,b,c) = min(min(a,b),c)

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time helping me to figure out this question. I was finally able to get the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers, I was finally able to determine the smallest number. The code works perfectly on MARS.

```
.data
Msg1: .asciiz "Enter the first integer: "
Msg2: .asciiz "Enter the second integer: "
Msg3: .asciiz "Enter the third integer: "

.text
     # Print the first message
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, Msg1
 syscall

 # Prompt the user to enter the first integer
 li $v0, 5
 syscall

 # Store the first integer in $t0
 move $t0, $v0

 # Print the second message
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, Msg2
 syscall

 # Prompt the user to enter the second integer
 li $v0, 5
 syscall

 # Store the first integer in $t1
 move $t1, $v0

 # Print the third message
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, Msg3
 syscall

 # Prompt the user to enter the third interger
 li $v0, 5
 syscall

 # Store the first integer in $t0
 move $t2, $v0

 # Determine the smallest Number
 blt $t0, $t1, L0
 blt $t1, $t0, L3


 li, $v0, 10
 syscall

 L0:
   blt $t0, $t2, L2
   blt $t2, $t0, L3

 L2:
   li $v0, 1
   move $a0, $t0
   syscall
   li, $v0, 10
   syscall

 L3:
   blt $t1, $t2, L4
   blt $t2, $t1, L5

 L4:
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall
    li, $v0, 10
    syscall

 L5:
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t2
    syscall
    li, $v0, 10
    syscall


 li, $v0, 10
 syscall
```

Comment: Hint: instead of duplicating the whole 2-syscall block, it would take a lot less code to just branch around `move` instructions and have the block of `li` / `syscall` appear once at the end, once you have the right integer in `$a0`.